# animate navigationbarbutton

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I would like to know if there is a way to make the right, navigation bar button appear when say an if statement is qualified.. so say if the user is filling out some details and then the if statment runs is there a way to make the button go from not being there to fading in and being selectable?

currently I just have it sitting there, but would be a nice user reward to show that the user has meet the needs to press the search button etc.

this is currently all I am doing.

```
if (blaa blaa) {
//Add search barbutton
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

first ,you should add the rightBarButtonItem to the navbar and set the alpha to 0.0

them try this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.alpha = 1.0f;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }];
```

**update**

in your code

```
if (blaa blaa) {
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setTitle:@"search" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: btn] autorelease];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.alpha = 0.0f;

}
```

then you can use the code above

**update**

sorry i checked the code , the UIViewControler will reset the barButtonItem property
so you must set is agian before the view show

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.alpha = 0.0f;
}
```

then when the button tapped

```
- (void) buttonTap:(UIButton*)btn
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView.alpha = 1.0f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }];
}
```

it should works!

Comment: Im not quite sure how to use this. I have tried it but its not working, I think it might be something to do with how I am initializing it in the first instance...?

Comment: :( am I supposed to add the button in interface builder or something? I have tried setting the alpha in your second lot of code to 1.0f and its still not showing up. So a little bit like what the heck.. just woundering if I need to do something more to get the customView ging correctly..

Comment: create UIBarButtonItem use **initWithCustomView** instead of **initWithTitle**  then you can use **customView** |  i tried my code and it works fine :)

Comment: LOL!!!! im so keen for this to work! I will keep trying lol so its all code no interface builder right?

Comment: perfect.. thought so but I dunno why its not working for me... so was like maybe i need to do something like that.

Comment: I have tried cutting it down to just **UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: btn];** and it still dosn't work... I wounder why?

Comment: Nope not working. I think maybe its something to do with my apps structure. I have a navigation controller thats declared in my appdelegate. then I have a rootViewController, which i am hiding the navigaiton bar. Then in the next viewcontroller which I go to, thats where I am trying to add/animate it from.. but it just dose not want to co-operate... thanks heaps for the help.. if you have any last ditch ideas I would be more than happy to hear them but if your outta ideas that all good.. I'll keep working at it and hope for a break through of some description. :)

Answer (score 1):

use -initWithCustomView to make a UIButton inside of a UIBarbuttonItem which in turn is inside the nav bar, PHEW!   Then you have complete access to the alpha of the UIButton, a luxury UIBarButtonItem does not afford.

Of course, this is all pre iOS 5 mumbo jumbo.  Use +appearance to animate your backgroundColor of the view from a 0.0 alpha to a 1.0 alpha (note, UIColor is not animateable in this case, use the CGColor property).

Comment: @CodaFi can you give some example how to use +appearance and where to use it.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to somewhat accomplish this would be to modify your buttons `setEnable` state. This will not change wether the button is visible but will toggle wether the user can interact with it, like so.

[image]

```
if (blahblah == YES) {
    [myBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];

}else {
    [myBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it worked well, however I am looking for something that starts with no button, then when the if statement is satisfied I would like the button to be animated into the view.